# Frames per second

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get the property FPS from a video that is recorded by a camera.

I use:

```
CvCapture* flujo_video = cvCreateFileCapture(argv[1]);
double parametro= cvGetCaptureProperty( flujo_video, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

The result of this is `-nan` and if I use an `int` format the result is `-2147483648`.

Comment: please **avoid** opencv's legacy c-api. you **must not** write code like that in 2015 any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look around in the web, you can see lots of people having problem with this parameter. It turns out that being thousands of cameras/codecs/formats openCV cant handle them all, so often you get 0, NaN (not a number) or other illogical parameter. This generally means that you can not get the FPS for your camera.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without using the deprecated C api:

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video file for reading
double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but the result is the same,